# NoMethodError (undefined method `gsub' for #<Hash:0x00000102ec5ab0>):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

in any of my controllers, using devise I have:

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!
```

If I'm not signed in, the redirect from devise to sign in is not working. Instead I get the following error:

```
Started GET "/settings/account" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-12-21 18:43:20 -0800
  Processing by SettingsController#account as HTML
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 3ms

NoMethodError (undefined method `gsub' for #<Hash:0x000001070a0a20>):


Rendered /Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@andyw/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (1.0ms)
Rendered /Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@andyw/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (2.2ms)
Rendered /Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@andyw/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (6.5ms)
```

Any ideas on how to debug this? Thanks

Comment: Any ideas? really appreciate it

Comment: Show us some code. What's `account` look like? You see anywhere that tries to do a gsub?